# Making a post request using jQuery with custom headers

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update a page using jQuery. I inspected the network to see what was happening and saw this:

```
Request URL:https://www.URL.com/api/projectStatus?statusId=11144371
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 201 Created

Request Headers
Cookie:
CSRF:
...etc

Request Payload:
{projectIds: [1050868563], statusId: 11144371}
```

I looked up the documentation for jQuery and saw this example:

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

I tried:

```
$.post("https://www.URL.com/api/projectStatus?statusId=11144371", {projectIds: "[1050868563]", statusId: "11144371"}
```

I'm getting a 403 error (bad request). I'm making this request in the console. Do I need to include all of the header information?

Comment: Well, since we don't know what the server-side source code is, we can't tell you if it checks for the headers. Usually an API requires an authentification. Some auth can be done by headers but it's usually an API Key given as a usual parameter
Can you contact the API service to get their expectations?

Comment: I cannot unfortunately :-( What would be the right way to pass in all of the headers?

Comment: I'll make an answer with the syntax to send headers as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax to send out headers along your request, the `Header_Name_One` is the custom name of your header, you'll have to specify every header you see from your request inspector, and the `Header Value One` it its value (has to be in quotes).

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://url.com',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            projectIds: 'you project ids values...',
        },
        headers: {
            Header_Name_One: 'Header Value One ',
            "Header Name Two": 'Header Value Two' 
// if the Header name has spaces, use quotes to surround it (like above)
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
function addUser(){    

    var json={
            "firstName": $('#firstNameId').val(),
            "lastName": $('#lastName').val(),
            "birthDate":new Date(),
            "email": $('#uemail').val(),
            "phoneNumber": $('#uNumber').val(),
            "password": $('#firstName').val(),
            "gender": $('#lastName').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
            url : "restful/user/",
            type : 'POST',
            data : JSON.stringify(json),
            contentType : "application/json",
            success : function() {
            console.log("OK");
        }};
```

I have something like this.Post throu ajax.It could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'test.php',
  data: {'name' : 'Elizabeth', 'age' : '56'},
  success: function(data){
   $('#display').html(data);
  }
});
```

type : type of request POST or GET

url : the url of the script you are posting to

data : the data you are sending with the request

success : the data returned from the request can be accessed through the success callback